# Use Javascript to run another file in directory

Tags: javascript, python, html

is there a way to use javascript to run another file? like lets say i want to run a python file and i want to use javascript to do so like im doing this:

example.js run --> example.py --> example.py(print("Hello World!")

so is this possible or not?

Comment: Do you want to read the file on the server or on the client?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do this with `NodeJS` and the [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) module.

This would be the JavaScript file:

```js
const { exec } = require("child_process")

exec("python example.py", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Here's the `example.py`:

```py
print("Hello, world!")
```

Here's that running on my machine:

[image]

Comment: Dude you are the BEST! Thank you so much! edit: just tried it again to make sure it worked a second time and it gave me an error i did but it into a function variable so is that the problem?

Comment: I don't quite understand what caused the error. Can you update the post to show the code you are trying to run?

Comment: ```const { exec } = require("child_process")

function run() {
exec("python example.py", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
}```

Comment: when i tried to run it i got an error

Comment: Do you have `NodeJS` installed on your machine? What was the error?

Comment: im actually running this on replit.com and the error is require is not defined and cannot access exec

Comment: Hmmm. Works fine for me on repl.it: https://replit.com/join/qprdhxucmm-dayun123

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't make a NodeJS repl. Do that, then create the main.py in that REPL and it should work.

Comment: i am using html im gonna switch to nodejs and use http

Comment: You can't access the filesystem from HTML. You could check out Pyodide if you want to run Python from the browser, though.